# Sony vaio vpcsa line in?

Tags: audio, sony-vaio, audio-recording

Hi does the Sony Vaio VPCSA have a line in contact? I could not find one and I want to use the computer for recording audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not according to the [Sony manual](http://www.docs.sony.com/release/VPCSA3_SB3_SC3_SE_series.pdf).

You'll have to attach a USB audio interface.

[image: USB Audio interface]